# WordPress lost password redirect issue

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am using WordPress site in sub directory /blog and the main site is not WordPress

Main site
https://intentwise.com/

WordPress website (sub directory)
https://intentwise.com/blog

The problem is my lost password is redirect to main website, Can u please help

For example
Redirect to https://intentwise.com/wp-login.php?checkemail=confirm

Not this
https://intentwise.com/blog/wp-login.php?checkemail=confirm

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^MY_IP
RewriteRule .* https://intentwise.com/blog/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: open your database table "wp_options" and verify that "siteurl" and "home" options have the correct url to "https://intentwise.com/blog"

Comment: its already add this url https://intentwise.com/blog/